# what is mean by rpn in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to develop a scientific calculator in iPhone and I have read with RPN is easy to develop calculator.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [Reverse Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_polish_notation).  It's just a different way to write mathematical expressions, though - it's not going to magically make you able to develop a calculator if you don't already know what you're doing!